# TimeGlider addEvent not reading enddate

Tags: jquery

I am using TimeGlider for some time event display..its great and fun but my issue is that I have to add all events dynamically and not though JSON file ..like all examples show .. the problem is that the addEvent method when adds an event with "enddate" does not show the background span that it should be showing.. however if you put the same event inside a json file..the span is visible .. further more the events added through addEvent do not show the enddate on mouse over which indicates that its not considering the "enddate" .

```
{
"id":"_now1",
"title": "nowEventere",
"date_display":"ho",
"description": "prttt",
"startdate": "2012-01-01 08:00:00",
"enddate": "2012-04-01 08:00:00",
"high_threshold":60,
"importance":"40",
"icon":"triangle_red.png",
"span_color":"#FF0000"
}
```

so the above event if in JSON file will show time span but

```
var event={
"id":"_now1",
"title": "nowEventere",
"date_display":"ho",
"description": "prttt",
"startdate": "2012-01-01 08:00:00",
"enddate": "2012-04-01 08:00:00",
"high_threshold":60,
"importance":"40",
"icon":"triangle_red.png",
"span_color":"#FF0000",
"timelines":["js_history"]
};
tg_actor.addEvent(event);
```

will only use the "startdate" .. could this be a bug and or there is something missing in the event?

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed the bug .. if you are using the downloaded folder .. look for JS file TG_Timeline.js

inside the file look for the method

```
tg.TG_Event = Backbone.Model.extend({ .......
```

at the end of initialize method look for the method call..

```
this.set(ev);
```

add the below line line above this method call

```
/*BUG FIX..Imran (20/09/2012) ..time span events added through addEvent method did not show time span .. span attribute was not being added*/
            if(ev.cache.span) // if span was set to true .. add attribute 
                ev["span"]=ev.cache.span;
```

it should look like

```
/*BUG FIX..Imran (20/09/2012) ..time span events added through addEvent method did not show time span .. span attribute was not being added*/
            if(ev.cache.span) // if span was set to true .. add attribute 
                ev["span"]=ev.cache.span;

            this.set(ev);
```

the fix simply adds the span attribute to the object.. which for some reason was not being added ..